# Azure Data flow new branch how data flow

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a **source1** in the image below, i am creating a branch from the **source1** and then in that I am doing join and then sink to **skin1**. my question is how the flow will work first it will completer the flow from **sources1** to **sink1** then it jumps to **NewBrach"Source1"** then join and skin, or it will run parallel

Run **Sequential**

Will it flow like 1->2>3->4->5>6
or

Run **Parallel**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends :)

It is non-deterministic and depends on whether ADF needs to block, waiting for any computation to complete in the other streams.

We are also working on adding UI gestures to control ordering.

For now, execute the data flow in a pipeline debug, then look at the execution plan using the eyeglasses icon to get a better idea of your parallelism.

Comment: Thanks Mark  :)  :)

Answer (score 1):

Just an Update if someone following this post-Microsoft has released the custom Sink feature.

Thanks @Mark

please check the Link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-sink